# Short Stay Schengen Business Visa: Cost for travelling and living

Tags: visas, schengen, netherlands, business-travel, applications

A company in Netherlands is inviting me for a face to face interview and is sponsoring my:

1. Flight Tickets
2. Hotel Accommodation
3. Travel Insurance

They have provided me with an invitation letter which says that they will pay for my flights and hotel accommodation. They have also sent me an insurance document. Now while filling up the visa form what should I answer to the question - "Cost of traveling and living during applicant's stay covered"

**Option 1 --**

Select "Sponsor/Host" and under the subcategory select "All expenses covered during the stay"

**Option 2 --**

Select "Sponsor/Host" and under the subcategory select "Other" and mention FLIGHTS, HOTEL & INSURANCE

Also, Select "by applicant himself" and under the subcategory select "Cash"

My gut feeling is to go with Option 2, but VFS website's sample form http://www.vfsglobal.com/netherlands/india/pdf/Visa_Application_Sample_Form_160217.pdf suggests going for Option 1. Any suggestions here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either is fine although Option 2 appears more comprehensive. You will after all be interviewed and have an opportunity to explain if it comes up. You will not be refused a visa by a competent consular simply because of this. I speak from my **personal** Schengen visa experience where ambiguities were clarified during the interview.

Comment: Great answer! This is one of the cases where official sources are extremely unlikely to exist and first hand experience is very valuable.

Comment: I have been advised to Select "Sponsor/Host" and under the subcategory select "Accommodation Provided" and "Pre-Paid Transport" and also select "Other" to mention INSURANCE. Would doing this be OK?

Comment: @Rakesh You are really worrying yourself too much over this minor detail. Either of the options you mention is okay. If you're going to be refused the visa, it won't be because of this. But yes I agree with `select "Sponsor/Host" and under the subcategory select "Accommodation Provided" and "Pre-Paid Transport" and also select "Other" to mention INSURANCE`.